# Similarity Measure/Matrix for data (recommender system)- Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, similarity

I am new to machine learning and am trying to try out the following problem.
Input is 2 arrays of descriptions with same length, and output is an array of similarity scores of first string from first array compared to first string in second array etc.

Each item in the array(numpy array) is a string of description. Can you write a function find out how similar between two strings by calculating how many identical and co-occurring word IDs there are, and assign it a score (one possible weight can be based on the frequency of co-occurrence vs sum of frequency of individual word ID). Then apply the function to two arrays to get an array of scores.
Please also let me know if there are other approaches you would want to to consider as well. 
Thanks!

Data:

```
array(['0/1/2/3/4/5/6/5/7/8/9/3/10', '11/12/13/14/15/15/16/17/12',
       '18/19/20/21/22/23/24/25',
       '26/27/28/29/30/31/32/33/34/35/36/37/38/39/33/34/40/41',
       '5/42/43/15/44/45/46/47/48/26/49/50/51/52/49/53/54/51/55/56/22',
       '57/58/59/60/61/49/62/23/57/58/63/57/58', '64/65/66/63/67/68/69',
       '70/71/72/73/74/75/76/77',
       '78/79/80/81/82/83/84/85/86/87/88/89/90/91',
       '33/34/92/93/94/95/85/96/97/98/99/60/85/86/100/101/102/103',
       '104/105/106/107/108/109/110/86/107/111/112/113/5/114/110/113/115/116',
       '117/118/119/120/121/12/122/123/124/125',
       '14/126/127/128/122/129/130/131/132/29/54/29/129/49/3/133/134/135/136',
       '137/138/139/140/141/142',
       '143/144/145/146/147/148/149/150/151/152/4/153/154/155/156/157/158/128/159',
       '160/161/162/163/131/2/164/165/166/167/168/169/49/170/109/171',
       '172/173/174/175/176/177/73/178/104/179/180/179/181/173',
       '182/144/183/179/73',
       '184/163/68/185/163/8/186/187/188/54/189/190/191',
       '181/192/0/1/193/194/22/195',
       '113/196/197/198/68/199/68/200/201/202/203/201',
       '204/205/206/207/208/209/68/200',
       '163/210/211/122/212/213/214/215/216/217/100/101/160/139/218/76/179/219',
       '220/221/222/223/5/68/224/225/54/225/226/227/5/221/222/223',
       '214/228/5/6/5/215/228/228/229',
       '230/231/232/233/122/215/128/214/128/234/234',
       '235/236/191/237/92/93/238/239',
       '13/14/44/44/240/241/242/49/54/243/244/245/55/56',
       '220/21/246/38/247/201/248/73/160/249/250/203/201',
       '214/49/251/252/253/254/255/256/257/258'], 
      dtype='|S127')

array(['151/308/309/310/311/215/312/160/313/214/49/12',
       '314/315/316/275/317/42/318/319/320/212/49/170/179/29/54/29/321/322/323',
       '324/325/62/220/326/194/327/328/218/76/241/329',
       '330/29/22/103/331/314/68/80/49',
       '78/332/85/96/97/227/333/4/334/188',
       '57/335/336/34/187/337/21/338/212/213/339/340',
       '341/342/167/343/8/254/154/61/344',
       '2/292/345/346/42/347/348/348/100/349/202/161/263',
       '283/39/312/350/26/351', '352/353/33/34/144/218/73/354/355',
       '137/356/357/358/357/359/22/73/170/87/88/78/123/360/361/53/362',
       '23/363/10/364/289/68/123/354/355',
       '188/28/365/149/366/98/367/368/369/370/371/372/368',
       '373/155/33/34/374/25/113/73', '104/375/81/82/168/169/81/82/18/19',
       '179/376/377/378/179/87/88/379/20',
       '380/85/381/333/382/215/128/383/384', '385/129/386/387/388',
       '389/280/26/27/390/391/302/392/393/165/394/254/302/214/217/395/396',
       '397/398/291/140/399/211/158/27/400', '401/402/92/93/68/80',
       '77/129/183/265/403/404/405/406/60/407/162/408/409/410/411/412/413/156',
       '129/295/90/259/38/39/119/414/415/416/14/318/417/418',
       '419/420/421/422/423/23/424/241/421/425/58',
       '426/244/427/5/428/49/76/429/430/431',
       '257/432/433/167/100/101/434/435/436', '437/167/438/344/356/170',
       '439/440/441/442/192/443/68/80/444/445/111', '446/312/23/447/448',
       '385/129/218/449/450/451/22/452/125/129/453/212/128/454/455/456/457/377'], 
      dtype='|S127')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should facilitate you with what you need in Python 3.x

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def jaccardSim(c1, c2):
    cU = c1 | c2
    cI = c1 & c2
    sim = sum(cI.values()) / sum(cU.values())
    return sim

def byteArraySim(b1, b2):
    cA = [Counter(b1[i].decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict").split("/"))
          for i in range(len(b1))]
    cB = [Counter(b2[i].decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict").split("/"))
          for i in range(len(b2))]

    # Assuming both 'a' and 'b' are in the same length
    cSim = [jaccardSim(cA[i], cB[i]) for i in range(len(a))]

    return cSim # Array of similarities
```

Jaccard Similarity score is used in this implementation. You may other scores, such as cosine or hamming, to your liking.

Assuming that the arrays are stored in variables `a` and `b`, the resulting function `byteArraySim(a,b)` outputs the following similarity scores:

```
[0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.038461538461538464,
 0.0,
 0.041666666666666664,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.08,
 0.0,
 0.05555555555555555,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.058823529411764705,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.05555555555555555,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0]
```